# OneDrive not available in FilePicker

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, onedrive

I am playing alittle with windows phone 8.1 app creating. Using C# and phone emulator in VS2013. I have read on microsoft's page that i should be able to see OneDrive in standard file picker (msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/windows/apps/dn263258.aspx):

> Use the built-in Windows features.
>
> Whenever possible, use the Windows features and UI to host or interact
>   with OneDrive. For instance, use the file picker provided by the
>   Windows.Storage.Pickers namespace for opening and saving files. As
>   another example, have your app use the Windows application data APIs
>   to save smaller pieces of data across a user's devices.

I am using standard code from tutorial like:

```
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

and it works but there is no OneDrive to choose. I have internet connection on emulated device and i am logged in to OneDrive.

Answer (score 0):

Have you integrated your file picker with the OneDrive contract?: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465192.aspx
You can also use the Live SDK single sign-on feature for Windows Phone here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn631823.aspx This way, your app should work for your testing purposes because you are already signed in.
I hope this helps!